# Extract information from nested dictionaries inside another dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

the dataset contains 25 columns 500 rows, one of the columns is "orderItems" that contain nested dictionaries, all keys of "orderItems" contain 1 - 15 dictionaries . take one random row, Ex:

```
dataset.orderItems[691581]
```

Result:

```
[{'product': 10152, 'price': 78.76, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 3584, 'price': 20.9, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 20308, 'price': 9.9, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 7619, 'price': 13.9, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 3795, 'price': 15.9, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 6504, 'price': 18.9, 'quantity': 2.0},
 {'product': 13720, 'price': 75.9, 'quantity': 1.0},
 {'product': 18419, 'price': 31.9, 'quantity': 1.0}]
```

Want to create 3 columns: "product", "price" and "quantity" so that it would fit all the information of all the dictionaries in these columns.  Example above would be plus 8 rows extracted from a single value of "orderItems". The price, product and quantity information extracted from "dataset.orderItems[691581]" would divided in these 3 columns each one to his proper column. Remember that somes keys have 1 dictionary, other have 15 (máx)

anyone can help me?

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: I tried to use 
`pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i): dataset.orderItems[i] 
                           for i in dataset.orderItems.keys()},
                       orient='index')`

But this code only bring 15 columns, containing the dictionary inside

The problem is that I'm very new in Py, so I can't do much.

Comment: So [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
list_df = []
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
   df_values = df.loc[i,"orderitems"]
   for i, row in enumerate(df_values): 
        list_df.append(pd.DataFrame([row]))
 df_values_final=pd.concat(list_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has returned a list for your row number. You can process it like this:

```
for dict_current in dataset.orderItems[691581]:
    i_prod_num = dict_current["product"]
    i_price = dict_current["price"]
    fl_quantity = dict_current["quantity"]
```

What you do next depends on what you want to do with these values.

Comment: This code only take the last dict, because one loop underwritting another